# GitHub Actions auto-approve not working on pull request created by GitHub Actions bot

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using two workflows inside my GitHub repository.

The first workflow gets triggered by every push on `dev` and bumps up the version inside a new branch `bump-version` and create a new pull request to `dev`.

```yaml
name: bump-version
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - 'dev'

jobs:
  bumpVersionNumber:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10
      - run: npm ci

      - name: Bump Version
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          npm run release

      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          commit-message: bump version
          title: Bump version
          body: Bump version to reflect release changes
          branch: bump-version
          base: dev
```

The second workflow should get triggered by every push and pull request to the newly created branch `bump-version`:

```yaml
name: auto-approve
on: 
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'bump-version'

jobs:
  autoApprove:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10
      - run: npm ci
         
      - name: Pull request number
        run: |
          echo "Pull Request Number - ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}"

      - name: Approve pull Request
        if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
        uses: hmarr/auto-approve-action@v2
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          pull-request-number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
```

The problem is that the second workflow `auto-approve` does not get triggered, when the new pull request is created or there is a push on the branch by the first workflow `bump-version`.

I would like to know why the second workflow `auto-approve` gets triggered by push on any branch but not the `bump-version` branch and why it's not getting triggered when a new pull request is being created from the branch `bump-version` to `dev`?

Does it has to do something with the fact that the pull request is being created by GitHub Actions bot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[By default](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow), when you use the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN` to perform tasks, events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN` will not create a new workflow run. This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive workflow runs.

If you do want to trigger a workflow from within a workflow run, you can use a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` to trigger events that require a token.

Here, you would have to use this PAT when calling the `peter-evans/create-pull-request` action:

```
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          commit-message: bump version
          title: Bump version
          body: Bump version to reflect release changes
          branch: bump-version
          base: dev
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```